# Is it defined anywhere (in the SQL spec, or ODBC spec, or something similar) what collation is used to resolve identifiers?

Tags: sql, odbc, collation

Not sure if this question is a good fit for stackoverflow as it's not specific to any particular database or api, but I can't really google an answer, or find one in, for example, the SQL-92 spec (it talks about collation, but seemingly only for data, not identifiers).

My question is, does SQL/ODBC take into account the possibility of different collations being used by different databases to resolve identifiers(i.e. columns, tables, scalar function names, etc)? I've seen mentions of doing case-insensitive matching (for example for ODBC catalog function arguments), but that's only a special-case for collations (along with the implicit-opposite of the binary collation), or is some 'default' collation assumed? It feels like an oversight...

Comment: Please tag your question with the brand of SQL database you are using. The correct answer is likely to depend on the implementation.

Comment: I'm not concerned with any particular implementation. I actually work on something that 'wraps' databases generically.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is likely to be implementation-dependent, so there's probably no dependable consistent behavior.

I can answer for MySQL.

- Objects that map to filesystem entries (like database/schema names and table names and view names and partition names), are case-sensitive, unless you're on an operating system where the filesystem is case-insensitive.
- Other objects like column names, triggers, stored procedures, and so on are case-insensitive. The INFORMATION_SCHEMA uses a collation of utf_general_ci (case-insensitive).

For more details, read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-collation-information-schema.html

Comment: Is the collation used for INFORMATION_SCHEMA the one used when parsing queries?

Comment: Not very well obviously

Comment: I read it again, and I'm still unclear... It doesn't seem to explicitly state anywhere how this table is involved in resolving column/table/etc references in queries.